# Entity Framework Linq IQueryable does not contain a definition for Contains

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, join, contains

I have the following (working) query

```cs
return _context.SubCategories
            .Join(_context.CategoryLinks,
             sc => sc.ID,
             cl => cl.SubCategoryID,
             (sc, cl) => new { SubCategory = sc, CategoryLinks = cl })
             .Where(x => x.CategoryLinks.CategoryID != CategoryID)
             .Select(x => x.SubCategory).Distinct();
```

But my problem is that it will return double records in the end as a subcategory can be linked to multiple categories.

So i.e. we are retrieving the subcategories that are linked to the category `Cat_1`.
`Sub_A` is linked to `Cat_1` but also to `Cat_2`, the query will filter out Sub_A from the result once as it is linked to `Cat_1` in the `CategoryLink` table. But in the end `Sub_A will` still be part of the `resultset` as it's also linked to `Cat_2`

So I thought if I'd retrieve the subcategories first (see code below) and then filter out the ones that have already been used with contains it would solve my issue.

```cs
var test = _context.CategoryLinks.Where(x => x.CategoryID == CategoryID);

IQueryable<DM.SubCategory> aaa = _context.SubCategories
          .Join(_context.CategoryLinks,
          sc => sc.ID,
          cl => cl.SubCategoryID,
          (sc, cl) => new { SubCategory = sc, CategoryLinks = cl })
          .Where(x => x.CategoryLinks.CategoryID != CategoryID && !test.Contains(x.SubCategory.ID))
          .Select(x => x.SubCategory);
```

However I'm getting an error when I try to do `test.Contains` which is;
`IQueryable<CategoryLink>` does not contain a definition for `Contains` and the best extension method overload `ParallelEnumerable.Contains<Guid>(ParallelQuery<Guid>, Guid)` requires a receiver of type `ParallelQuery<Guid>`

Why is it not allowing me to use contains in above query? I tried replacing var test with `IQueryable< DM.CategoryLink> test` but that didn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IQueryable<T>.Contains` have two overloaded methods, and both do not accept arbitrary type. If you want to check whether item is in the collection, use `IQueryable<T>.Any` instead.

From you code snippet, I guess that it might be `test.Any(t => t.ID == t.Subcategory.ID)`

Comment: Ah okay, I did try that but that results in the error "Cannnot convert lambda expression to type 'CategoryLink' because it is not a delegate type.

https://i.imgur.com/x16KNed.png

Comment: Just use `Any` like in my answer.

Comment: I completely missed that... my bad. With .Any it works fine :)